# Adding Configuration Activity prevents Pending Intent from working

Tags: android, widget, android-pendingintent

I have a simple widget that is a single button, that when pressed it cycles through the Audio Manager Ringer Modes.  I recently added a configuration activity and now when adding the widget to the home screen the button doesn't work until the automatic update period expires.  I have confirmed, from log files, that I'm kicking off the `onUpdate` when the configuration is complete, but the button still doesn't work.  What am I missing to make the `setOnClickPendingIntent` work immediately?

**appwidget-privider XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:targetCellHeight="1"
   android:targetCellWidth="1"
   android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
   android:updatePeriodMillis="100"
   android:initialLayout="@layout/main"
   android:previewImage="@drawable/preview"
   android:configure="com.example.myWidget.ConfigActivity"
/>
```

**Widget onUpdate**

```
public class RSwitch extends AppWidgetProvider {

public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent(Context paramContext) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(paramContext, RingStateChange.class);
    intent.setAction("com.example.intent.action.CHANGE_RING");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(paramContext, 555, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
}

public static void buildRingerModeChangeIntent(Context paramContext){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED");
    RingStateChange rsc = new RingStateChange();
    paramContext.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(rsc, filter);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context paramContext, AppWidgetManager paramAppWidgetManager, int[] paramArrayOfint) {
    super.onUpdate(paramContext, paramAppWidgetManager, paramArrayOfint);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(paramContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Button1, buildButtonPendingIntent(paramContext));
    RingStateChange.PaintWidget(paramContext, remoteViews);
    buildRingerModeChangeIntent(paramContext);
}
}
```

**Config Activity**

```
public class ConfigActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_config);

    //Create the returnValue intent from the calling Intent
    Intent sender = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = sender.getExtras();
    int appWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
    if (extras != null) {
        appWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
    }
    Intent resultValue = new Intent().putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);


    NotificationManager myNOtificationMgr = (NotificationManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (!myNOtificationMgr.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) { //Check is access has already be granted
        Button dndBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.launchDNDbtn);
        dndBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                view.getContext().startActivity(i);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
            }
        });
    }
    else { //Do not show Config if DND access has already been granted
        callOnUpdate(appWidgetId);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
        finish();
    }
}

public void callOnUpdate(int appWidgetId ) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE, null, getApplicationContext(), RSwitch.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, new int[] {appWidgetId});
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
}
```